# JQ run dynamic command from inside the object

Tags: jq, eval

In JQ is it possible to execute the command from same object?

Take and example below

```
{
"cmd": ".name += \" Smith\" | .name",
"name": "John"
}
```

If you see i have name and cmd as two keys. If you run the text from cmd's value in [JQPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/0U_vMF-fTCJ). You will see below object `"John Smith"`

Is it possible to do it using single JQ query ?

Comment: No, jq does not have an `eval` function (or similar) that could decode and run a jq filter from a JSON string. Outputting it by one jq instance, and having the shell use this as the filter for another instance, is the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks @pmf for your helpful insight!!

Answer (score 0):

As @pmf pointed out, jq does not provide an "eval" function, so if you really wanted to evaluate jq expressions, you'd have to write your own, which is probably not what you want.

However, there is a reasonable alternative. Since you are evidently willing to include some kind of expression to be evaluated in your JSON, you could piggy-back off jq's support for array-paths, and write a simple evaluator. For example,
if you were willing to write your JSON template as:

```
{
  "name": [["firstname"], " Smith"],
  "firstname": "John"
}
```

then this little bit of infrastructure:

```
def ispath:
  type == "array" and all(.[]; type | IN("string","number") );
  
# eval . in the context of $context
def eval($context):
  . as $x
  | if type == "string" then .
    elif ispath then $context | getpath($x)
    elif type == "array"
    then map( eval($context) ) | add
    elif type == "object"
    then map_values(eval($context))
    else tostring
    end;
```

would allow you to achieve essentially what you want by:

```
{
  "name": [["firstname"], " Smith"],
  "firstname": "John"
}
| eval(.)
```

Comment: Thanks @peak my case is bit complex.. I have lots of filters which I want to apply..